# How do i organise a table to show all people with groups within the table?

Tags: tables

Im designing a table.
On the table, it is made up of all people.
People are set up with targets, the DR, LC and LP and [6],[7],[8] in the picutre
If a person has been assessed they are scored against the target and are marked in red or green (below or above the target)
People can be part of a group (e.g. Amazon HR group in the 'Setup Status') or they may not be..

How do i organise the table where i dont have to replicate the target across each row for the person but yet show all people in all groups?

Do i need to organise the people into groups on the table?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A table is a two-dimensional structure.  The problem is that you are trying to display more than two dimensions of data in a single table.  There is no intuitive way to do that.

The best solution is probably:

1. **Summarize** information displayed in this table to what is most important to view at a high level.  I don't know what the correct summary is for your use case, but it could be things like:

   - % targets passed.
   - Are there any outstanding targets?
   - Were any targets failed?
2. Open another, **detailed view** for an individual when you click on the appropriate summary data.

Answer (score 0):

A huge con of grouping data is that groups will overrule sorting rules. For example, if you sort on DR DESC now the person with the green 8 will be shown on top right? However, when you have more data and sort while grouped, it will show the group in which you have a person with the highest score, at least that is what I would expect. Another person with the second highest score is then shown somewhere in the second group. Do you see what I mean?

Therefore, an important factor here is the size of your dataset. In addition, I think the table doesn't get more overwhelming because of the labels (at least considering the table as it is in your screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve the problem with this table view.
But there are a handicap, if there are too many records would not be a useful table representation.

[image: Colored Table]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe show the targets like "7 out of 7 (100%)" instead and then have that text have the color coding. It wasn't clear to me that the white boxes contained the target. I would not worry about replicating the target. I need the target to make sense of the score. But you do have to contextualize it.

However I'm not sure why some scores seem to be greater than the target and if that's a sketching error or an actual case.